# Default order status shows "processing " when order is placed in magento?

Tags: php, magento

Currently I am working on a Magento and I install new `Magento 1.9.1` on the **localhost**.

When order is placed for "**cash on delivery**" its status shows "**processing**".
while it should be in "**pending**".

I have set "**pending**" status  in payment method option for "**cash on delivery**".
But it shows "**Processing**".

How set default status as "**pending**".

If someone help is more appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

Go `System>Configuration >Payment Method > Cash` On Delivery

And set the state to pending.